# jQuery jqGrid Change The Font Size For Only The Caption On This Page

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jqgrid

In this jQuery & Coldfusion code, how would you change the font size of just the Caption? I would prefer not to update the CSS so it does it to every instance on every page of the Caption. Just the Caption on this page.

No more details available from the customer.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/JS/jquery/ui1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/JS/jquery/external/jqGrid532/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/JS/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/JS/jquery/ui1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/JS/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/JS/jquery/external/jqGrid532/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/JS/jquery/external/jqGrid532/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/JS/jquery/external/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
    window.gridInfo = <cfoutput>#globalDataObj.getColumnInfo()#</cfoutput>;
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#data_grid_display").jqGrid({
            url:'<cfoutput>#application.url#/#application.directory#</cfoutput>/cfc/TheLoadsutil.cfc?method=getData',
            datatype: 'json',
            colModel: window.gridInfo.colModel,
            headertitles: true,
            sortable: false,
            pager: $('#Pager'),
            shrinkToFit: false,
            width: 1205,
            height: 400,
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList:[100, 150, 200, 250,500],
            sortorder: 'desc',
            sortname: 'TheLoadsID',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Loads',
            recordtext: '{0} - {1} of {2} Loads Records',
            pgtext: 'Page {0} / {1}',
            onSelectRow: function(id){},
            gridComplete: function(){
            },
            toolbar: [true, "top"],
            jsonReader: {
               root: "ROWS",
               page: "PAGE",
               total: "TOTAL",
               records: "RECORDS",
               cell: "",
               id: "1"}
            
        });

        //append the new button
        jQuery('#t_data_grid_display').append('<input type="button" value="New Record" title="Create a New Record" onclick="initializeEditModal(0,0);">');
        
    });//document ready 

    // -- grid column selector
    pickColumns = function () {
        $("#data_grid_display").jqGrid('columnChooser', {
        dialog_opts: {
            modal: true,
            minWidth: 470
            }
        }); 

      };
  </script>
```

Comment: You don't have to modify the external css files, but you must use CSS.  Use your browser's "Inspect Element" tool to find the caption's css class. Then override the font on the current page only. See (CSS Specificity Rules)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @SOS write is absolutely correct.

In your case it is just this line

```
#gview_data_grid_display .ui-jqgrid-caption {
    font-size:  15px;
}
```

Note the gview_ prefix